# Azure Single Database GeneralPurpose Edition in Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

So I need to create a Single Database in Azure through Terraform. 
The requirements are 8vCores/3TB.

What should be the edition that I should be passing in resource parameter "azurerm_sql_database"-->"edition"?

The documentation at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/sql_database.html 
says -- Valid values are: Basic, Standard, Premium, or DataWarehouse.

But when I create a similar database through portal, and query the DB, it says edition is 'GeneralPurpose'.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure recently introduced a second set of choices which you can think of as a parallel (but more powerful) business model.  Basic/Standard/Premium still work, but you now have additional choices.  The new model supports separation of compute/memory from storage/iops more formally.  It exposes General Purpose and Business Critical + exposing each generation of CPU (gen 4 vs. gen 5).  As a rough starting point, you should think of standard as being close to general purpose and business critical is close to premium.

SQL DW is a somewhat different offer that is based on the PDW/APS scale-out appliance model (run as a service).  So, while 3TB will fit on a single node in current generation 5 HW, if you want to run a DW SQL DW is a great choice if you think you will grow further, need scale-out processing, etc.  You should not think about going between SQL DW and  without app changes - in fact, you can't change between those two sets once you pick one.

You can read more about the new business model here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-vcore

This week a new option (Hyperscale) was announced as well which gives scale-out storage within SQL DB

Comment: So the requirement for the project is Gen 4. The problem is, I don't know what to pass for Edition in terraform for Gen4/8vCores/3TB Single DB.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you are looking at terraform.io rather than here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-databases-manage#azure-cli-manage-logical-servers-and-databases and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-db-create